Load video in flask server python passing the chunks from zmq socket to it
I have the following problem, I am using Hololens glasses, where there is an API: https://IP/api/holographic/stream/live_high.mp4?holo=true&pv=true&mic=true&loopback=true’ that provides a streaming that the user sees. The idea is that the user will have a pair of glasses in his private network, therefore, from the outside it will not be possible to access to make the request directly, since it is a private IP.
Therefore, the idea would be to have two scripts, one that is responsible for making the HTTP GET request and get the video chunks and this, send it through a zmq socket to another script that will be on my server. The second script will be in charge of receiving through the socket all the chunks and load them in the video using a Flask Response.
The problem is that testing both scripts in one and in local it works, but when I split it in two, it doesn't load the video, I think it could be a yield problem because it receives so many data in a row that it doesn't have time to process everything.
Script Request
import argparse
import signal
import threading
import zmq # type: ignore
import requests

ZMQ_ADDR = "localhost"
ZMQ_SUB_PORT = 5756
ZMQ_PUSH_PORT = 5755
TOPIC_PUSH = "stream"

class HololensRequestAgent():

    def exec_streaming_agent(self):
        try:
            with requests.get(self.hololens_url, stream=True, verify=False) as req:
                if req.status_code == 200:
                    for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        self.push_socket.send_multipart([TOPIC_PUSH.encode('utf-8'), chunk])
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error reading data: {}".format(e))

    def start(self):
        self.stop_recording = False
        self.thread.start()
    
    def stop(self):
        self.stop_recording = True
        self.thread.join()
    
    def __init__(self, topic, hololens_ip):
        print("API Hololens {}".format(hololens_ip))
        self.hololens_url = "https://{}/api/holographic/stream/live_high.mp4?holo=true&pv=true&mic=true&loopback=true".format(hololens_ip)
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.exec_streaming_agent)
        # create ZMQ socket instance 
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        # create SUB socket
        self.sub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        print("SUB tcp://{}:{}".format(ZMQ_ADDR, ZMQ_SUB_PORT))
        self.sub_socket.connect("tcp://{}:{}".format(ZMQ_ADDR, ZMQ_SUB_PORT))
        self.sub_socket.subscribe(topic)
        # create PUSH socket
        self.push_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        print("PUSH tcp://{}:{}".format(ZMQ_ADDR, ZMQ_PUSH_PORT))
        self.push_socket.connect("tcp://{}:{}".format(ZMQ_ADDR, ZMQ_PUSH_PORT)) # esto habrá que cambiarlo al server

    def close(self, sig, frame):
        print("Signal '{}' received".format(signal.strsignal(sig)))
        self.stop()
        print("Closing connection...")
        # close connection
        print("HololensRequest agent closed.")
        self.context.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Hololens agent')

    parser.add_argument('--topic', type=str, default="", help="Topic to subscribe to. (Subscribe to all by default)")

    parser.add_argument('--hololens_ip', type=str, default="", help="IP from hololens. (Subscribe to all by default)")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("Starting hololens request agent...")
    hololens_agent = HololensRequestAgent(
        topic=args.topic,
        hololens_ip=args.hololens_ip
    )

    for signal_code in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
        signal.signal(signal_code, hololens_agent.close)

    print("Starting to run hololens")
    hololens_agent.start()


Script Receiver
import argparse
import signal
import threading
import zmq # type: ignore
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request # type: ignore

ZMQ_SUB_ADDR = "localhost"
ZMQ_SUB_PORT = 5756

app = Flask(__name__)

class HololensReceiverAgent():

    def receive_chunks(self):
        try:
            while True:
                chunk = self.sub_socket.recv_multipart()[1]
                print(chunk)
                yield chunk
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error reading data: {}".format(e))    
            yield b''        

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.thread.join()

    def __init__(self, host_addr, port, topic):
        self.topic = topic
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_chunks)
        # create ZMQ socket instance
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.sub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        print("tcp://{}:{}".format(host_addr, port))
        self.sub_socket.connect("tcp://{}:{}".format(host_addr, port))
        self.sub_socket.subscribe(self.topic)

    def close(self, sig, frame):
        print("Signal '{}' received".format(signal.strsignal(sig)))
        self.context.destroy()
        shutdown_server()

def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video')
def video():   
    return Response(hololens_agent.receive_chunks(), mimetype='video/mp4')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Hololens agent')
    parser.add_argument('--host_addr', type=str, default=ZMQ_SUB_ADDR, help='Host address (default 127.0.0.1)')
    parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, default=ZMQ_SUB_PORT, help='Subscriber port')
    parser.add_argument('--topic', type=str, default="", help="Topic to subscribe to. (Subscribe to all by default)")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("Starting hololens receiver agent...")
    hololens_agent = HololensReceiverAgent(
        host_addr=args.host_addr,
        port=args.port,
        topic=args.topic
    )

    for signal_code in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
        signal.signal(signal_code, hololens_agent.close)

    print("Starting to run hololens")
    hololens_agent.start()

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002, debug=True)


Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHb7eAEDeHQAdHd4AAF7/AP/dAADmEuIAYwAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAjUGUyNWBAQQI1BlNWAxQEECNQZWA2AUBBAjUGA2cgFAQQI1A2dDIBQEECNQNnUyAUBBAjUDYFMgFAQQI1A0BTIBQEECNQFAUyAUBBAjUhQFMgFAQQIwIUBTIBQEECIUAgUyAUBBAUAhIFMgFAQUAhQSBTIBQEAhQEEgUyAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Hololens Video</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="hololens-video" autoplay controls width="100%"></video>
    <script>
        const videoElement = document.getElementById('hololens-video');
        videoElement.src = '/video';
    </script>
</body>
</html>


I hope the video doesn't stop and I continue with the streaming.
